# How to get the analytical solution of this equation set

Tags: equation-solving

There is a equation set:

```
{2 x^2 + 49 - 7 x - 2 x Sqrt[x^2 + 49 - 7 x] Cos[rad] == (7 - x)^2, 
 2 x^2 + 49 - 7 x - 2 x Sqrt[x^2 + 49 - 7 x] Cos[rad + Pi/3] == 49}
```

I want get the x-value's exact solution.But the `Solve` cann't work.

Comment: Play around with `Reduce`, maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Reduce` gives a solution. Here I've eliminated the trivial $x=0$ solution and also specified $-\pi \le rad \le \pi$.

```
sol = Reduce[And[
   2 x^2 + 49 - 7 x - 2 x Sqrt[x^2 + 49 - 7 x] Cos[rad] == (7 - x)^2, 
   2 x^2 + 49 - 7 x - 2 x Sqrt[x^2 + 49 - 7 x] Cos[rad + Pi/3] == 49,
   x != 0, -Pi <= rad <= Pi], x, Reals]
```

[image]

Since each term is a condition on rad followed by an equality for x we can extract a piecewise function for x:

```
xsol = Piecewise[{#2[[2]], #1} & @@@ List @@ sol]
```

[image]

which looks like this:

```
Plot[xsol, {rad, -Pi/3, 2 Pi/3}]
```

[image]

To check, here's a contour plot of both equations. The purple bits are where both are true:

```
ContourPlot[{
  2 x^2 + 49 - 7 x - 2 x Sqrt[x^2 + 49 - 7 x] Cos[rad] == (7 - x)^2,
  2 x^2 + 49 - 7 x - 2 x Sqrt[x^2 + 49 - 7 x] Cos[rad + Pi/3] == 49},
 {rad, -Pi, Pi}, {x, -20, 20},
 ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0.5, Red], Opacity[0.5, Blue]},
 AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

[image]

**Update**

I've just noticed that you can remove the `Reals` domain from `Reduce` and get a solution in terms of Tan functions which you can `FullSimplify` to get for x:

```
-7 + 42 Cos[rad]/(3 Cos[rad] + Sqrt[3] Sin[rad])
```